# Login using Twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

Good morning,

I tried a lot of times following some tutorials to login my App (it's my first App) using Twitter but I'm not able to do it.

I have followed the Facebook guide and now I can login using Facebook but I can't do the same using Twitter because the guide is really weird and confusing.

I'm not an expert, because that's my first time using Twitter login, that's why I need some examples or a good tutorial to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some useful and handy tutorials links

1 - [iOS 7  - Twitter Integration](http://codegerms.com/login-with-twitter-example-with-ios-tutorial-using-oauth/)

2 - [Ray wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5)

3 - [Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMm5t4APGMM)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try with the first one. I hope it works.